# ¿Cómo declarar en android Studio un tipo image?

Tags: android, android-studio, sql-server

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Estoy haciendo un metodo registrar a la base de datos desde android usando retrofit.

Mi tabla Firma Sql Server

```
create table Firma
(idFirma int,
firma image)
```

Mi duda es mi clase Firma en android Studio como declaro esa variable firma.

Comment: Entre la app Android y la base de datos hay una aplicación intermedia que sirve de API. En la API qué tipo de dato es firma?

Comment: Ah ok no me percate de eso gracias, esta en bytes.

Comment: Entonces en la clase Firma, la propiedad `firma` debe ser un arreglo de bytes `byte[] firma;`

Comment: @Dum la imagen proviene de una url o es un recurso dentro de la app?

Comment: recurso dentro del app, una firma

Comment: Pero es una tabla Microsoft Sql Server o es SQLite? @Dum

Comment: esta en Sql Server

Comment: El tipo de dato image va a ser retirado en una versión futura de SQL Server. Se recomienda que utilices el tipo varbinary(max) en su lugar.

Comment: bytes y lo abres facilemte con el framework glide.